# JQuery delay doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, delay

I have the follwoing AJAX/JQuery script:

```
    function changeModalBodyContent(content,time) {
        $(".modal-body").empty();
        $(".modal-body").delay(time).html(content);
    }
    //twitter bootstrap script

    $("button#delete").click(function () {
        var modalText = $(".modal-body").html();

        changeModalBodyContent("<div class='progress progress-striped active'><div class='progress-bar' style='width:100%;'></div></div>",0);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "deleteArticleType.php",
            data: { 'typeID': lastClickId },
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                $("tr[data-id='" + lastClickId + "']").remove();
                $("#message-placeholder")
                .html("<div class='alert alert-dismissable alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button><strong>sucess!!!</strong></div>");
                changeModalBodyContent(modalText,2000); 
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I want that the text in the second call for the function  `changeModalBodyContent` would displayed after sometime and not immediately, I tried the code above but it didn't work.

Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delay was built for animation queues but you could use `queue`:

http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback-next-

> .queue( [queueName ], callback( next ) )

```
    $(".modal-body").delay(time).queue(function(next){
      $(this).html(content);
      next()
    });
```

Note that Zepto.js does support neither `delay` nor `queue`.

Comment: As your answer shows, the Queue isn't just for animations - it can be used for any actions that should happen sequentially.